# Scrolling doesn't work on mobile view

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mobile

The scroll work is well done on desktop view but it doesn't work on mobile or portable devices' view. I found likely same solution but they couldn't solve mine. I'll appreciate for your help.

This is my site's address.
https://blueinternet-mm.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.mCustomScrollbar` class has pinch-zoom, remove it, here is screenshot

http://prntscr.com/kb6woq

Comment: Hey @Armin, may I ask u one more favor. "More details" links in head sliders do not work on mobile view, too. I can't find solution yet.

Comment: Don't use whole url just put #home/aboutus i n href="", and you have some event on click of that button, when you click it adds class "disabled" for a second, take a look at that

Comment: yes. I just can't find what cause that 'disabled" to be appeared.

Comment: Try debugging it with force on attribute change, sorry i don't have time to help with that now...

Comment: Ok. Thank you @Armin.